# Web client for Mercurial with update support?

Tags: mercurial, repository, webclient, tortoisehg

Is there such a thing as a web-based equivalent of the repository explorer /manager for Mercurial?
I know there's hgserve and I've seen SCM Manager but as far as I can see, these will only let you browse and push.
What I'm looking for is a web client with support for update and commit (and maybe also pull) commands.
BTW I'm not looking for the 'update on push' hook.

Comment: RhodeCode can do add/edit/delete files from web interface, and also pull changes from remote repositories also from web interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should give [Kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org/) a try! It is a full-featured source code management system with support for both Mercurial and Git. It has a ton of features and allows you to edit files directly in the browser.